# Can recommendation systems be created for other data other than images?

Tags: machine-learning, datasets, recommender-system

Can recommendation systems be created (using machine learning) for other data other than images?

For audio or video content, is it necessary to use a dataset of actual audio and video files, respectively, or is text information about the file enough for the recommendation system?

Answer (score 4):

Recommendation systems can be applied for anything, as long as you have sufficient training data.

The most important inputs to the recommendation system are not "audio files or video files".

Wikipedia gives you the list:

- Similarity matrix
- Item attributes
- User activities and behaviours
- User profile

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system